# Enable command shortcuts for Intellij for mac

Tags: macos, intellij-idea

I am using Intellij on a mac. When I was installing it, it asked whether I wanted to use the traditional shortcuts, based around the control modifier key, or to use the command key. I chose the latter but when I when I tried using it, it doesn't seem to work. Instead, only control shortcuts can be used. I can't find a way to change this in the settings; all the online documentations I've consulted point to an area in the settings called keymap which I can't seem to find. Searching for it using Intellij search function, under Help, doesn't yield returns.

How do I enable command shortcuts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keymap is in the preferences, which can be found in the **IntelliJ IDEA** menu.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Wow. I'm an idiot. I've been reaching the Preferences menu through "File". For me, keymap does not appear under that one. So, I tried accessing the preferences dialogue through "IntellliJ IDEA", which is to the left of "File" and I found it... Thanks for the help.